# using tf.scatter_nd(idx, update, shape) with shape having values that are dynamically allocated

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to update the value in a vector at some index. I've found [tf.scatter_nd](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd) to do what I want. But I'm batching the operation such that I have an array `batch_size*5`, where each row is the vector of size 5 that I'm updating. My `batch_size` is determined at runtime.

In using [tf.scatter_nd](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd), the shape argument takes a tensor which is the shape of the tensor to be produced. However if the first dimension is determined at run time, (such as if it is the batch size), then I get an error:

```
TypeError: Input 'shape' of 'ScatterNd' Op has type int32 that does not match type int64 of argument 'indices'.
```

This error is actually due to the shape variable having the values : [None, 5]. ie to produce a tensor that is of size `batch_size*5` updated with updates of size `batch_size` and using indicies of size `batch_size'.

How would I correctly use tf.scatter_nd() on a space that is dynamically allocated?

Comment: Did you try to cast it : tf.cast(var, tf.int32)

Comment: No, I haven't. But can you cast a None type to int32?.

Comment: It's not the dImensions that are in int64 but the elements inside the Tensor, so yes you can cast it and solve this error. As follow : 
    tf.scatter_nd(tf.cast(indices, tf.int32) , ... )

Comment: Its not the indicies argument I'm having an error with, but the shape argument.  One of the elements inside the tensor is None, as the tensor contains the shape of the output of scatter_nd()

Comment: Your error exactly describes a mismatch between your shape format and your indicies format. Did you try the cast ?

Comment: I'd previously  tried to cast indicies using tf's .to_int64() and it would not cast a Nonetype.

Comment: Did you try tf.cast? With int32 on your indices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic shape, such as `tf.shape()`

Look at the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np

inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, 5])

new_inputs = tf.scatter_nd(indices=[[0], [2]], 
                           updates=[[1,1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1,1]],
                           shape=tf.shape(inputs))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    _new_np = sess.run(new_inputs, feed_dict={inputs: np.zeros([4, 5])})
print(_new_np)
```

Is it what you want?

Comment: This works (ie gets me past the error), and is probably correct, but I'm still working through getting the graph to compile, if it does I'll mark it up.